# Calculating sum of two negative binary numbers in php 7.1

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, php-7.1

I'am trying to understand how making an addition of two negative numbers in PHP 7.1. So, I read these questions in stackeoverflow:

- [When should I use a bitwise operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705838/when-should-i-use-a-bitwise-operator)
- [PHP calculating with negative numbers gives wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834377/php-calculating-with-negative-numbers-gives-wrong-values)

I tested this script:

```
<?php 
 echo (~5) + (~7); // output: -14
```

But I don't understand why the result is -14. Tying to solve manually, I did like this:

```
~5 => (1011)
~7 => (1001)
```

`(1011) + (1001) = 0100 => 8 != -14 the output of php script`

Where is the error?

Comment: Because  `~5` is `-6` and `~7` is `-8`.

Comment: Did you mean to have minus symbol `-`? You have a tilde `~`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the function of the ~ bitwise operator (Tilde)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129744/whats-the-function-of-the-bitwise-operator-tilde)

Comment: @u_mulder So, ~5 = (1011) = -6 and ~7 = (1001) = -8?

Comment: I don't understand where `1011` comes from, as far as I know `5` is `101`, inverting 0 to 1 and vice versa gives you at least `1........010` depending on your pc (32 or 64 bits).

Comment: My pc is 64 bits and I did like this:  5 = (0101) => ~5 = (1011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading few examples in [php.net](http://php.net/) I fond a very good demonstration:

> The NOT or complement operator ( ~ ) and negative binary numbers can be confusing.
>
> ~2 = -3  because you use the formula  ~x = -x - 1  The bitwise
>   complement of a decimal number is the negation of the number minus 1.
>
> NOTE: just using 4 bits here for the examples below but in reality PHP
>   uses 32 bits.
>
> Converting a negative decimal number (ie: -3) into binary takes 3
>   steps: 1) convert the positive version of the decimal number into
>   binary (ie: 3 = 0011) 2) flips the bits (ie: 0011 becomes 1100) 3) add
>   1 (ie: 1100  + 0001 = 1101)
>
> You might be wondering how does 1101 = -3. Well PHP uses the method
>   "2's complement" to render negative binary numbers. If the left most
>   bit is a 1 then the binary number is negative and you flip the bits
>   and add 1. If it is 0 then it is positive and you don't have to do
>   anything. So 0010 would be a positive 2. If it is 1101, it is negative
>   and you flip the bits to get 0010. Add 1 and you get 0011 which equals
>   -3.

[source from php.net](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.bitwise.php#105821)